# overflow directive always disabled [Workaround Available]

Tags: angular

**Original:**

I am having a hard time getting my matTooptip directive to work properly in the case of when using a mat-select element. The issue is that no matter what, even if ellipsis is present, the tooptip is always disabled. This directive, btw, works fine for

My directive looks as follows

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTooltip } from '@angular/material/tooltip';

@Directive({
  selector: '[tooltipIfEllipsis]'
})
export class TooltipIfEllipsisDirective {

  constructor( 
    private matTooltip: MatTooltip,
    private elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) { }
    @HostListener('mouseenter', ['$event'])
    setTooltipState(): void {
        const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
        this.matTooltip.disabled = (element.scrollWidth <= element.clientWidth &&  element.clientHeight >= element.scrollHeight);
    }


}
```

Every time I hover over my mat-select, which is defined as follows, the directive is always evaluating to true. How can I make this directive work with a mat-select, or is there a different way to check for ellipsis?

```
<mat-select 
        class="dropdown-select"
        [(value)]="sessionTypeId" 
        (selectionChange)="onDropdownChange($event)"
        matTooltip=""
        defaultTooltip="'No assigned session types for this coach'"
        conditionalMatTooltip
        [conditionalTooltip]="selectedSessionType?.Name + ' - ' + selectedSessionType?.Length + ' Minutes'"
        [conditionMet]="sessionTypes.length > 0"
        tooltipIfEllipsis
        placeholder="'Select a session type'"
        name="sessionTypes">
        <mat-select-trigger *ngIf="sessionTypes.length == 0">
            <span [ngStyle]="{ 'color': '#2199E8' }">Select a session type</span>
        </mat-select-trigger>
        <mat-option style="color: #2199E8" *ngIf="sessionTypes.length == 0" [value]="'N/A'">
            Select a session type
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let c of sessionTypes" [value]="c.Id" [matTooltip]="c.Name + ' - ' + c.Length + ' Minutes'" tooltipIfEllipsis>
            {{c.Name}} - {{c.Length}} Minutes
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an interesting work around, so from what I gather applying a mattool tip like in the original directive to a mat-select is actually not quite possible due to how it is implemented.

However, if we consider that a VERY rough guesstimate of char to pixel is {fontSize}/2. Then we can come to the following new directive instead:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[tooltipRoughPixelGuess]'
})
export class TooltipRoughPixelGuess {

  constructor( 
    private matTooltip: MatTooltip,
    private elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) { }

    @HostListener('mouseenter', ['$event'])
    setTooltipState(): void {
        const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
        const roughCharToPixel = Math.ceil(15/2);
        this.matTooltip.disabled = element.textContent.length * roughCharToPixel < this.elementRef.nativeElement.offsetWidth
    
        if(!this.matTooltip.disabled && this.matTooltip.message == "") {
          this.matTooltip.message = element.textContent;
        }
    }
}
```

This appears to work well in my use cases so far. It is not an ideal solution, but as engineers sometimes we need to settle for good enough.